# embed:title== two words?

Tags: ee2

A client asked me to took over his website recently to update on his behalf so the site was produced by a previous developer so I am quite new to Expression Engine.

Only pages with single word can show the active menu colour (background + border) when we are on the current page but not other pages with two words.

Heres the code:

```
<a href="{site_url}team" {if embed:title=='Our Team'}class="active"{/if}>Our Team</a>
<a href="{path='services/taxation'}" {if embed:title=='Taxation'}class="active"{/if}>Taxation</a>
```

I found that one word would work fine but not two words. I tried:

```
Our Team
Our%20Team
Our-Team
Our_Team
```

Any suggestion? 
Thanks heap!

Comment: I'm guessing the title is not what you think it is. What is output to the HTML source if you add this to the template? `*{embed:title}*` (please include the asterisks)

Answer (score 1):

It should work. Did you tried:

```
{if "{embed:title}" == "Our Team"} class="active" {/if}
```

Comment: Indeed I have done that one but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the url_title instead ?